# htaccess redirect root to subdirectory but allow index.php in root AND query strings to function

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I had a question similar to this, and it was answered. However, the answer led to another concept and now I have the following question. (User "anubhava" was able to answer the original question.)

Let me explain, our situation is this:

We are launching a new website using Joomla, however, we wanted all of the old website's in-bound links to continue to function (as we have a lot of content in WordPress on the old website). So, using htaccess, we were able to have all requests to the primary domain name redirect to a sub-directory with the new Joomla website in it. [So as an example, requests for www.example.com get redirected to www.example.com/PORTALsite due to the htaccess code, which is what we want.]

Further, this code also allows for requests to the Home page of the old WordPress website to still function (the old website we are replacing). [So as an example, www.example.com/index.php will still function and load the old WordPress site, which is what we want.]

Only if the request is for the domain name alone (www.example.com) will it redirect to the new Joomla website's Home page (located at www.example.com/PORTALsite/), but if the request is for the old website's Home page (located at www.example.com/index.php) it will allow this and load the old WordPress website.

Here's the htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+[\s?]
RewriteRule ^$ /PORTALsite [R=301,L]
```

**HOWEVER, my problem now is this**: There are many in-bound links where the old WordPress website's index.php page is omitted and only a query string is attached (indicating a Page name on the old website via WordPress). However, because the code above sees this as a call just to the primary domain name alone (as it "ignores" the query string) it also redirects this to the new Joomla website. **We do not want this to happen**! Any help, please?

**Example of what the problem is now**:

1. (not a problem) requests for the primary domain name are successfully redirected
   to the new Jooma website, thus www.example.com will redirect to
   www.example.com/PORTALsite, as we want and as it should.
2. (not a problem) www.example.com/index.php successfully loads the old WordPress
   website's Home page though, as we want and as it should.
3. **however this is the problem**: in-bound links that have no file name but include a
   query string, such as www.example.com/?page_id=56 are also getting
   redirected to the new Joomla website (for example, www.example.com/PORTALsite/?page_id=56) AND WE DO **NOT** WANT THIS TO HAPPEN.

   we want www.example.com/?page_id=56 to redirect to
   www.example.com/index.php?page_id=56 and load the content from the
   old WordPress site. **how do I make this happen based upon the htaccess code above?**

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
# Match requests for /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+[\s?]
# Don't match requests for page_id=n
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !page_id=[0-9]+
# Redirect to /PORTALsite
RewriteRule ^$ /PORTALsite [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you Jon! Worked perfect!